# Adjustable height bed with table

Tags: bedroom, table

I am trying to create a very simplistic bed, with four legs and a top. I want its height to be adjustable up to 8 inches, which would then also serve as a table.

How do I make the legs adjustable up to 8 inches?

Comment: Have 4 extensions that screw on to each leg.

Comment: "Adjustable" as in "stack on top of bricks or phone books", or as in "push a button and the top moves up"?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too broad. For starters you'd need to describe or show us the bed design. Then, there are many ways to do this, each of which may or may not be suitable for your needs. Please research ideas on your own and return if you have specific problems implementing your approach.